# ¿Cómo habilitar o des habilitar filas de una tabla con un checkbox?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una tabla que se llena de manera dinámica en la cual hay un checkbox con el cual quiero que si se marca el checkbox se habilite la fila en la que se encuentra el checkbox.

mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
<table className="table table-hover" style={{ border: 'none' }}>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Selected</th>
      <th scope="col">Room type</th>
      <th scope="col">Bed type</th>
      <th scope="col">Price per night</th>
      <th scope="col">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  {this.state.room.map((item, index) => (
    <tbody key={index}>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onChange={this.Handlecheck}
            type="checkbox"
          ></input>
        </td>
        <th scope="row">{item.room_category_desc}</th>
        <td>
          <select className="form-control form-control-sm col-sm">
            <option>Select</option>
            {item.bed.map((bedtype) => (
              <option key={bedtype} value={bedtype}>
                {bedtype == 'K' ? 'King' : bedtype == 'D' ? 'Double' : ''}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>$653.31</td>
        <td>$4,573.20</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  ))}
</table>
```

Tengo una funcion con la cual se cambia el estado del checkbox

```
Handlecheck(checked){
  this.setState({checked: checked.target.checked});
}
```

mi problema es que si chequeo algun checkbox se marcan todos los que hay en la tabla y no solo el que marque.

Quedo a sus ordenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea un state que guarde el índice de la fila y si está checkeado o no. Inícialo con:

```
this.state = {checkedRow: {}}
```

luego recibir como parámetro el index, que a la vez representaría el número de fila:

```
Handlecheck(checked, row){
  const newCheckedRow = {...this.state.checkedRow, [row]: checked}
  this.setState({checkedRow: ...newCheckedRow});
}
```

finalmente considerar el `index`, tanto para ver si está checkeado como para pasarlo como parámetro de `Handlecheck`:

```
<input
  checked={this.state.checkedRow[index]}
  onChange={this.Handlecheck(index)}
  type="checkbox"
></input>
```